# How to put 2 modules on top of each other?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, module-display

i basically want a contact information form module on top of a google maps module so the google maps are a type of background and the form itself is around 30% of the container. This is perfectly illustrated in smartaddons sj zaga template, but i cant find anywhere here how it is done. I presume it has something to to with z-index in css for which one will be in front, and probably a setting of margin-left set to a minus value for the second module?

I also want to arrange in a similar manner a slideshow module underneath a reservation form..

Comment: I assume you have set both modules to the same position and then changed the order in which they're displayed using the default Module parameters

Comment: i am actuall modifying the plugin which generates both the map and the contact info on the same module position, and expanding the divs to 100% then display-inline, then set the margin of the second div to -500px; then try to assign z-index:1 to the map div and z-index:2 to the contact info div but no matter what i do the google maps div always show on top... i dont know why.

Comment: It's extremely hard to tell without seeing anything visual

Comment: restorantdalia.com scroll to the bottom a little bit to see how it is now, resorantdalia.com/admin scroll to the bottom how it should look like

Comment: You can see what the admin page uses: `position:absolute;` for the content over the map.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the two modules (the map and the contact form) both use a div with the same class:

```
<div class="ctajax-element">
    // Map displayed here
</div>
<div class="ctajax-element">
    // Contact form displayed here
</div>
```

This means that you can't target any of the `<div>` elements individually. You have to change these div's (or add an additional class) in order to be able to target each of them.

This should work:

```
<div class="ctajax-element mymap">
    // Map displayed here
</div>
<div class="ctajax-element myform">
    // Contact form displayed here
</div>
```

Then add the following CSS:

```
.ctajax-element.myform {
   position: absolute;
   width: 40%!important;
}

.ctajax-element.mymap {
   width: 100%!important;
}
```

The result should look something like this:

[image: Contact form with Google map]